# Upgrading Graphics Card for Video Rendering

Tags: after-effects, premiere, adobe, hardware, adobe-media-encoder

I currently have a GTX970 4GB card that I use in my video rig. I can edit and render and every works fine. I do video production for longer events. So a rendered video might be 2 hours long.

I'm curious if upgrading to a PNY VCQP2000-PB would help my render times or make my realtime editing and viewing any better? Should I go for this or a 1070gtx? I do game a little on the machine but maybe if it didn't work as well for gaming I'd get more done. :)

I use a pci nvme ssd for my main os card and I have raided ssds for my storage drives. I only have 16gb of ram though, so maybe adding more there would help? Running a 6core Intel CPU.

Thanks!

Comment: Related reading: http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/compare.php?cmp%5B%5D=3712&cmp%5B%5D=3521

Comment: I compared the two but its hard to find a real world comparison of encoder performance.

Comment: That's true... If price is a factor, I'd go with the 1070. If it's not, one option is find a place that will let you do returns (like Amazon, maybe) and order both. Test them, decide which one you like, send the other back. If you have to just choose one, I think I'd go with the 1070. Unless you do CAD, a 1070 will outperform a quadro at the same price point. I don't know if it's better for Adobe, but I know on  Da Vinci Resolve, GTX architecture is better than Quadro.  More reading: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/939738

Comment: For AE you'd get the most bang for your buck if you buy more RAM. Have a look how your system's resources are being used during a typical intensive render. What is maxing out? Is it the RAM or the GPU or CPU? Spend $$ accordingly.

Comment: Im exporting video now and I'm hitting 100% of my cpu, its an i7 5820k 6 Core Processor. Memory is only hitting 75% 12gb of 16gb. I guess I could upgrade my processor but not too far without swapping out mbs. Maybe ram and video card is the way to go for now then maybe next year do the proc mb.